# PUT routes broken by scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my application, I have several resources scoped into 'admin' as follows (in routes.rb):

```
scope 'admin', :as => 'admin' do
    resources :events
end
```

So when I go in to use the #new or #update methods through the form, I end up getting the ActionController exception saying `No route matches [PUT] "/admin/events"`.

`rake routes` produces the following:

```
        admin_events GET    /admin/events(.:format)             events#index
                     POST   /admin/events(.:format)             events#create
     new_admin_event GET    /admin/events/new(.:format)         events#new
    edit_admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id/edit(.:format)    events#edit
         admin_event GET    /admin/events/:id(.:format)         events#show
                     PUT    /admin/events/:id(.:format)         events#update
                     DELETE /admin/events/:id(.:format)         events#destroy
```

_form code:

```
<% if notice %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @event, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :url => url_for(:controller => 'events', :action => 'index') do |f| %>
<fieldset>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :event_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls date-selects">
      <%= f.datetime_select :event_date, :start_year => 2012 %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :publish_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls date-selects">
      <%= f.datetime_select :publish_date, :start_year => 2012 %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :blurb, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :blurb, :class => 'span6 wysi' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :graphic, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.file_field :graphic %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :tix_link, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.url_field :tix_link %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), admin_events_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post here the form's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your form tag from:

```
<%= form_for @event, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :url => url_for(:controller => 'events', :action => 'index') do |f| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @event], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

This will use the proper `admin` scope and properly generate the url, depending if the `@event` is persisted on the database or not.